# Generic C# Copy Constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, copy

What would be the best way to write a generic copy constructor function for my c# classes?
They all inherit from an abstract base class so I could use reflection to map the properties, but I'm wondering if there's a better way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create a shallow copy **efficiently** with reflection by pre-compiling it, for example with `Expression`. For example, [like so](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/browse_thread/thread/d9722a51b04300a/0edae91abc1c0f1a#0edae91abc1c0f1a).

For deep copies, serialization is the most reliable approach.

Answer (score 23):

A copy constructor basically means you have a single parameter, which is the object you're going to copy.

Also, do a deep copy, not a shallow copy.

If you don't know what deep and shallow copies are, then here's the deal:

Suppose you're copying a class that has a single row of integers as field.

A shallow copy would be:

```
public class Myclass()
{
    private int[] row;
    public MyClass(MyClass class)
    {
        this.row = class.row
    }
}
```

deep copy is:

```
public class Myclass()
{
    private int[] row;
    public MyClass(MyClass class)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<class.row.Length;i++)
        {
            this.row[i] = class.row[i];
        }
    }
}
```

A deep copy really gets the actuall values and puts them in a new field of the new object, whilst a shallow copy only copies the pointers.

With the shallow copy, if you set:

```
row[3] = 5;
```

And then print both rows, both prints will have 5 as value of the 4th number.
With a deep copy however, only the first print will have this, since the rows don't have the same pointers.

Comment: You can use `row.clone()` as C# allows for primitive arrays to be cloned.

Comment: Doesn't the above code fail due to `row` never being initialized?

Answer (score 20):

Avoid reflection if you can. Each class should have the responsibility of copying its own properties, and send it further to the base method.

Comment: so just to clarify, it'd be best if you had a custom copy constructor on each class that explicitly mapped the properties?

Comment: I would.  How hard is it to write?  Certainly easier to read at a glance than a reflection-based method.

Comment: Yes, I would recommend that approach.

Comment: It's not hard to read and it's certainly easy to write, however there are maintenance issues to consider. If you add a new property to the class you need to update the copy constructor and tests which is pretty easy to forget.

Comment: I would disagree about updating the copy constructor.  And depending on what the new property changed I'm not sure that you'd need to do more than just re-run your existing tests.  Adding another get/set pair doesn't require new unit tests for each.

Comment: how would you copy the newly added properties if you don't update the copy constructor?

Answer (score 11):

Here's a constructor that I'm using. Note that this is a shallow constructor, and rather simplistic, due to the nature of my base class. Should be good enough to get you started.

```
public partial class LocationView : Location
{
    public LocationView() {}

    // base class copy constructor
    public LocationView(Location value) {
        Type t = typeof(Location);
        PropertyInfo[] properties = t.GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in properties)
        {
            pi.SetValue(this, pi.GetValue(value, null), null);
        }
    }
    public Quote Quote { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: One line-able: `foreach (var propertyInfo in typeof(LocationView).BaseType.GetProperties()) propertyInfo.SetValue(this, propertyInfo.GetValue(obj_to_copy_parameter, null), null);` you could also use a field initializer to only ever read GetProperties once.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic I tend to avoid one-liners when it sacrifices read-ability.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218989/best-way-to-clone-properties-of-disparate-objects I came up with a generic extension to shallow-clone common properties

Answer (score 0):

You may reference valueinjecter and fasterflect nuget packages and use:

```
public class Myclass()
{
    private string _property;
    public MyClass(MyClass obj)
    {
         this.InjectFrom(obj.DeepClone());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why no upvotes? Can someone please confirm whether this works?